# PDO if row count syntax

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on some PDO/PHP (switching over for old school PHP methods), I am not getting my syntax right. The idea is pretty simple, I need to disable a button if `rowCount() == 4` and echo text `disabled`. Any idea what I doing wrong?

```
<?php  
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ');
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

$disabled = if { ($stmt->rowCount() == 4) echo "disabled"; } else { echo " "; }
} 
?>
```

HTML Button:

```
<span class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-file" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Maximum 4 Boxes" <?php echo = "$disabled"; ?> >
```

Any links to help educate myself more on these statements would be really appreciated too, my english is not so good!

Comment: Either `<?php echo "$disabled"; ?>` or `<?php="$disabled"; ?>`

Comment: You need to need to read the documentation of rowCount()

Comment: MIght be some issues with rowcount-doesn't always return the correct numbers.

Comment: So, you want to disable only ONE button if number of rows in the table is 4? Or you want to display 3 all right and 4th disabled? **Please, try to make your question to bear any sense**. You are responsible for all these hasty rep-hunters who lose their precious rep instead of gaining it.

Comment: If you only care about the count, what you really need to do is `SELECT COUNT(*)` to get the number of rows, not the rows themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea where you got this:

```
$disabled = if { ($stmt->rowCount() == 4) echo "disabled"; } else { echo " "; } }
```

but AFAIK this is a syntax error.

The correct way to do an inline if is:

```
$disabled = ($stmt->rowCount() == 4) ? "disabled" : " ";
```

as seen [in the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: `$disabled = ($stmt->rowCount() == 4) ? "disabled" : " ";` without `;` after `"disabled"`

Comment: @NDM Thank you, I am not good with english, I wish people did not downvote. I am only learning, i sorry for not clear question.